# Drop down menu for blogger

Tags: javascript

I am creating my first personal blog and I have a problem (you have to know that I am not good at using pc^^).

My website is:
http://test12341234.blogspot.it/

(I don't want to promote it. But if you can, please cancel the link after I have received an answers).

I could create a drop down menu with javascript on blogger (I have copied a code that I found while surfing on internet). 
Now I have to solve the last problem: I would like to know how I can regroup all the posts inside the drop down menu since I can't link the posts, which I published andh which you can see in the Homepage, to the drop down menu (where I would them to be regrouped, but where I can't find anything).

I hope you have undertood (I'm not english and I speak as a little child^^).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry the right link is:

Comment: http://testo12341234.blogspot.it/

Comment: @Awakening Are you trying to show all posts/link that you uploaded on your blog in dropdown menu? So that user can type comment and select the link/post that he wants to comment on?

Comment: I am showing the posts not to promote my website (I have to change the URL in the future) but to make sure that people can see the problem.

Comment: Anyways, people can comment on if they notice a problem

Comment: Since my website isn't written in english, I translate two words:  "LABELS" is "Etichette" (in my website); "COMMENT" is "Commento".  :)

Comment: I have solved my problem.

Comment: If you want, you can cancel the answer.;)